# How to use Redux and Axios in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

This is my Login Page :

```
class Login extends Component {

  /*define constructor for state props*/
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
     }

     /*Define the after submit form*/
     handleSubmit(e) {
      // Stop browser from submitting the form.
      e.preventDefault();

      this.form.validateFields();

          if (!this.form.isValid()) {
            console.log("Not valid arguments");
          } else {

  This is my function for Axios post values
       Validate here or directly when setting state.
      Then send a POST request to your endpoint.

      axios.post('http//127.0.0.1:8000/user/login', {
          email: this.state.email,
          password: this.state.password
        })
        .then(function(response) {
          /*response from json*/
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
    }

    handleChange(e) {

      this.form.validateFields(e.currentTarget);

      this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      });
    }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="container">
      <h3 className="jumbotron">Redux Form Validation</h3>
      <FormCode onSubmit={this.submit} />
    </div>
```

This is my function for Validations using redux-forms

Define validation in front

> const validate = values => {
>           const errors = {}
>           if (!values.password) {
>             errors.password = 'Required'
>           } else if (values.password.length > 15) {
>             errors.password = 'Must be 15 characters or less'
>           }
>           if (!values.email) {
>             errors.email = 'Required'
>           } else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)) {
>             errors.email = 'Invalid email address'
>           }
>           return errors
>         }
>
> ```
> const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) => (
>     <div>
>       <label className="control-label">{label}</label>
>       <div>
>         <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} className="form-control" />
>         {touched && ((error && <span className="text-danger">{error}</span>) || (warning &&
> ```
>
> {warning}))}
>             
>           
>         )
>
> ```
> let FormCode = props => {
>   const { handleSubmit, pristine, submitting } = props;
>   return (
>     <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
>       <div className="form-group">
>         <Field name="firstName" component={renderField} label="First Name" />
>       </div>
>       <div className="form-group">
>         <Field name="lastName" component={renderField} label="Last Name" />
>       </div>
>       <div className="form-group">
>         <Field name="email" component={renderField} label="Email" />
>       </div>
>       <div className="form-group">
>         <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting} className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
>       </div>
>     </form>
>   )
> }
> FormCode = reduxForm({
>   form: 'contact',
>   validate,
> })(FormCode);
> ```

```
export default FormCode;
```

I´m getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: You must either pass handleSubmit() an onSubmit
>   function or pass onSubmit as a prop

Comment: how about `dispatch` this function

Comment: @shahabvshahabi my other question it´s if the syntax is correctly.

Comment: i really dont have any knowledge about redux but i suggest you to use `mobX` it is so powerfull than redux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above solution will work. Anyway, I'd like to leave you my opinion.

First, you should not use a mix of `setState` and Redux. If you are going to use Redux, so better to handle all the application's state on Redux.

Then, in your React's components you should only call to Redux's actions. Let's suppose you have an action named `loginWithEmailAndPassword`. Your submit function would be like this:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // There is not need to pass email and password since you have
  // those values in "state".
  this.props.loginWithEmailAndPassword();
}
```

And your Redux action would be like this:

```
export function loginWithEmailAndPassword() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    // Get email and password from state.

    return axios.post('YOUR_URL', { email, password })
      .then((success) => success && dispatch(someNextAction()));
  };
}
```

This is super super fast written, so I'm not sure if it works. It's only "pseudo-code" explaining how I would manage the solution for your problem.

Take a look at `getFormValues` of redux-form (https://redux-form.com/6.1.0/docs/api/selectors.md).

Hope it helps.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onSubmit(values) {
    // this === component
    console.log(values);
  }

render() {
    // this is a property that is being passed to your component
    // on behalf of reduxForm
    const {handleSubmit} = this.props

    return (
      // handleSubmit takes a function that you define and you 
      // pass that to handleSubmit and it takes care of the 
      // reduxForm validation and if everything is good then it
      // will call the callback this.onSubmit and passes the values
      // out of the form to work with
      // this.onSubmit is the callback function
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
        <Field
          label="Title For Post"
          name="title"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        <Field
          label="Categories"
          name="categories"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        <Field
          label="Post Content"
          name="content"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
```